# Adsense code not showing

Tags: adsense

My adsense code won't show. Code is in there, and is in there for weeks...Still not showing..
http://www.ecompanies.nl/pilot/diensten/seo/breda.html

I think it should be jQuery or Google Maps javascript interfering or something.
Don't see any javascript errors..

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using doubleclick to serve adsense ads or are you using the straight adsense code they gave you?

Comment: Just the code from the adsense dashboard..

Comment: You could try serving the ads on a fresh page with no other javascript and see what happens or try generating a fresh ads and testing that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering the same problem...It looks like an Adsense problem. Seems like the ads only show up after Google Adsense bot spidered the page. On new pages on my sites, it takes 1 or 2 days for the ads to show up. Very strange..

Comment: Never had this afterwards. After couple of days ads where shown. 

On your site:
-the 'hey' page shows me no adsense ad
-the 'new page' page does show me 1 adsense banner 

Suggest you wait and see if this solves itself before putting too much time into it..

Regards,
Bas

Comment: Thanks for you reply, much appreciated.
 Do you think the issue because of foreign language ?

Comment: Don't think so. Had 25+ Adwords sites without this problem.